# Account login callback in client similar to the server-side onLogin()

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Is there a similar callback on the client-side to the `Accounts.onLogin()`?  I am creating a custom signin process, and when the user logs in successfully I would like to route them back to the page that they were going to that triggered the login.  I am using Iron Router for routing.

**Additional Information**

So, what I am trying to do is to write a generic plugin for login/logout using Iron Router for routing.  The way I am tying in is by creating a method in my plugin that you call via the `onBeforeAction` of the route like so:

```
onBeforeAction: function() { AccountUtils.authenticationRequired(this, ['ADMIN']); }
```

This method checks if the user is logged in and if they have the required roles.  If they are, it lets the route continue and the user goes on no problem.  If they are missing roles, they get forwarded to the notAuthorized page, and if they are not logged in, they get forwarded to the signin.

One of the "features" I am trying to get working is configurable signin/signout pages.  The user will do this by calling a `config()` method on the my AccountUtils object.  If no config is set, there are defaults.  So, I have a default signin/signout page offered with override.  This part is working, just not the forwarding part.

The issue is I am trying to tie into the login so I can forward the user back to the path they hit to trigger the auth challenge.  What I was trying to do is set a Session var during the challenge part, then have something triggered after successful login that reads the Session var and re-routes.  If I tie into the `Accounts.loginWithPassword()`, then anyone overriding my signin page will also need to write their own trigger to foward.  I am thinking maybe there might be a way if I have a wrapper template around the signin and signout pieces, but I am not sure how I would get triggered on the user signing in.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the callback of the login method (it's not run until you're successfully logged in):

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword(user, password, function(error) {
  if (! error) {
    Router.go('route.name');
  }
});
```

Comment: The thing is I am trying to build sort of a "framework", where the user can replace the signin/signout pages through config.  And I can't guarantee the user will add the proper signout hooks in that case.  I was hoping there would be another way other than hooking into template code.